# Генерация HTML-страницы используя с++

Tags: html, c++, xml, c++builder

Нужно сгенерировать отчет по работе программы.

Просто текст не подойдет, потому что данные необходимо представить таблицей. Использовать `Word` или `Excel` нельзя,  потому был выбран `HTML`.

Так как данные будут браться на определенных отрезках времени, постоянно заново генерировать код на `HTML` построчно и записывать в файл (чтобы сформировать удобочитаемый вывод в виде таблицы), особо смысла не вижу(хотя мб только если в том же цикле), потому решил узнать, имеет ли право на жизнь такой вариант, как использование `XML`-файла с последующей конвертацией в `HTML`?

Так как необходимо сделать код универсальным, шапка будет меняться от даты, от времени, от используемого канала, какое значение будет использоваться в этом канале, а как это реализовать не особо понимаю. А с первым вариантом не совсем понимаю как правильно перенести создание таблицы, но нашел пример [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206604/create-html-reports-using-c)
Пример вывода в HTML:

```html
<p> Дата: 02.03.2016  Время: 10:24:33 </p>
<p> Канал: 1</p>
<p>
 <table align= &quotcenter&quot border= &quot2&quot cellpadding=&quot1&quot style=&quotwidth: 500px&quot >
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <b>Номер</b> 
  </td>
  <td>
   <b>Значение</b>
  </td>
  <td>
   <b>Отклонение</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>  0 </td>
  <td>  0,00000000 </td>
  <td>  0,00000000 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Ничего особенного нет по идее. Ну напишите отдельные функции/классы, которые будут генерировать шапку, заголовок таблицы и отдельный элемент. Если нужна гибкость, используйте интерфейсы/виртуальные функции. Это всё основы, так что думаю, что их объяснять не надо. Где ваша проблема?

Comment: @VladD Да я по ходу дела пока задавал вопрос сам на него и ответил:D в приведенной мною же ссылке есть все необходимое.