# Отчет в HTML используя c++

Tags: html, c++, report

Сам .html создаю как текстовый файл, разобрался [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503221/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D1%81). Есть шаблон "шапки" таблицы, хочу заполнить недостающие элементы в цикле, получая данные из массива.
Шапка [тут](https://gist.github.com/zakamaldin/aea873a2ba54220f59225652d1c0bb2f) и что должно быть в итоге(заполняю таблицу данными из массива) [тут](https://gist.github.com/zakamaldin/022921923ed0c6c7e98c338c3126c37f). Думал еще сделать таблицу в таблице и заполнять уже ее, но все разъезжается [тут](https://gist.github.com/zakamaldin/e53142e420bf14303644bd03bfcdf3a6).

Так как приходится писать в файл построчно,придется вставлять функцию, которая дополняет ряд, в каждом месте где записывается ряд в файл. потому и хочу узнать как это дело упростить. За ранее спасибо.
Код на с++:

```
   void HtmlRow(int& cells, int& data , string& t, ofstream& fout)
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < cells; ++i)
    {
     fout << t << "<td>" << data << "</td>" << endl;
    }
   }
   //шапка
   string t1 = "\t";
   string t2 = "\t\t";
   string t3 = "\t\t\t";
   string t4 = "\t\t\t\t";
   string t5 = "\t\t\t\t\t";

   ofstream fout("report.html");
   fout << "<!DOCTYPE html>" << endl;
   fout << "<html>" << endl;
   fout << t1 << "<head>" << endl;
   fout << t2 << "<title> Title </title>" << endl;
   fout << t1 << "</head>" << endl;
   fout << t1 << "<body>" << endl;
   fout << t2 << "<table border = 1 bordercolor = \"black\">"  << endl;
   fout << t3 << "<tbody>" << endl;

   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Канал</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td width = 5 rowspan=2>Направ- ление движения</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td colspan=2>Угловое положение</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Мини- мальная скорость</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Резуль- таты</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td colspan=2>Угловое положение</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>50% от мини- мальной скорости</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Резуль- таты</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td colspan=2>Угловое положение</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Макси- мальная скорость</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>Резуль- таты</td>" << endl;
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A1</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A2</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A1</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A2</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A1</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>A2</td>" << endl;
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   //конец шапки
   //first row
   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>1</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>+</td>" << endl;
   HtmlRow(12,1,t5,fout);
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   //second row
   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>-</td>" << endl;
   HtmlRow(12,2,t5,fout);
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   //third row
   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td rowspan=2>2</td>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>+</td>" << endl;
   HtmlRow(12,3,t5,fout);
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   //fourth row
   fout << t4 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t5 << "<td>-</td>" << endl;
   HtmlRow(12,4,t5,fout);
   fout << t4 << "</tr>" << endl;
   fout.close();
```

В итоге решил пойти по простому пути, и вынес запись ряда в отдельную функцию:

```
    void HtmlRow(vector<int>& Channel , string& ChannelName, string& t1, string& t2, ofstream& fout)
{
   //плюс
   fout << t1 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t2 << "<td rowspan=2>" << ChannelName <<"</td>" << endl;
   fout << t2 << "<td>+</td>" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < Channel.size()/2; ++i)
   {
       fout << t2 << "<td>" << Channel[i] << "</td>" << endl;
   }
   fout << t1 << "</tr>" << endl;
   //минус
   fout << t1 << "<tr>" << endl;
   fout << t2 << "<td>-</td>" << endl;

   for (int i = Channel.size()/2; i < Channel.size(); ++i)
   {
       fout << t2 << "<td>" << Channel[i] << "</td>" << endl;
   }
   fout << t1 << "</tr>" << endl;
}

void ReportHtmlComplex(int& Channels)//количество рядов
{

   /*
       шапка
   */
   vector< vector<int> > Data;
   //заполняем вектор векторов данными, для разных каналов

   vector<string> ChannelName;
   //заполняем названиями каналов

   //записываем ряды
   for(int i = 0; i < Channels; ++i)
   {
       HtmlRow(Data[i], ChannelName[i],t4, t5, fout);
   }

   /*
       закрываем таблицу и html-файл
   */
   fout.close();
}
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь в обсуждении.

Comment: @Abyx как заполнить нужные мне ячейки в цикле? делать на каждую строку свой цикл? не особо хочется, потому решил спросить как это можно реализовать проще.

Comment: @Abyx был вариант написать функцию для заполнения ячейками строку типа f<<"<tr>"; моя функция которая добавляет(<td></td><td></td><td></td>) f<<" </tr>", но тогда нужно вызывать функцию несколько раз, чего не особо хотелось, ибо раздувается код

Comment: По-моему, кода на плюсах не хватает...

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил, хочу убрать повторяемость кода, потому и решил обратиться за помощью

Comment: Я бы разделил дизайн таблицы в html и business-logic. То есть данные для таблицы запихал в довольно простой xml. А потом пропустил его через xslt например с помощью libxslt для получения html. В результате - форматирования html будет отдельно, циклы для заполнения строчек таблицы - отдельно.

Comment: Не думали об использовании шаблонных движков, например mustache https://github.com/no1msd/mstch это здоровы бы упростило логику и позволило бы вынести отдельно шаблон страницы.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan большое спасибо! Это в принципе то, что я и искал, но по запросам "создание отчетов html" выдавало инструменты, используемые в вебе(php, js, python), что мне не подходило, (десктоп приложение, а отчеты для внутренних нужд). Посмотрю, как можно реализовать то, что мне нужно, через этот движок. Если разберусь что и как, обязательно выложу решение. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: предлагаю пойти ещё дальше и взять такую идею https://ideone.com/vbVdYX